# Slot method called in the wrong thread (pyqt)

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

This class suppose to handle a long task in a separate thread.

Despite moving my object to a new thread, and  using queued connection, the signal is handled at the main gui thread instead of `self.thread`. The main gui thread is the thread that did called `startit` of course..

This is the code:

```
class DoLongProcess(QObject):

    def __init__(self,task):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self._task=task
        self._realtask=None
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.run,Qt.QueuedConnection)

    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        self._realtask()


    def startit(self,*params):
        self._realtask= partial(self._task,*params)
        self.thread.start()
```

I use pyside6. I tried to to split `__init__` into two methods and moving the thread from outside. Also tried without the QueuedConnection attribute (which suppose to do this exactly). None of this had an effect.

Do you know why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: You might want to change your title and description to something like "slot method called in the wrong thread", since that way you avoid any ambiguity with POSIX signals (which are unrelated to your question, but also referred to by the same word "signal" and also get called in the context of an arbitrary -- often "wrong" -- thread)

Comment: Is this class getting the signal from a different QThread? Is there another class in your code?

Comment: There are many more classes in my code :) yes, as mentioned, it is called from the gui thread.

Comment: I actually have a very similar code that work with emitting signal directly to the object slot (immediate thread.start in init). It works. I decided to use it. Still don't know what is wrong.

Comment: The gui thread is called by sys.exec_